# Is it possible to create a GitHub issue from Intellij IDEA (Android studio)?

Tags: android-studio, github, intellij-idea

I know that IDEA (and AS) supports GitHub issues as contexts and we can watch them, create commits etc. But I wonder is it possible to create an issue directly from AS?

Answer (score 4):

IDEA supports GutHub as a source of issues to create Task from.
It is not possible to do vice versa or create an issue on GitHub from IDE directly.

AFAIK, there are no plugins to do so either, at least I was not able to find one in JetBrains plugin repo.

A feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171494 We need huge amount of votes to be visible among other 140505 issues :-D

Answer (score 0):

you can use code stream plugin to do this. Though codesteam plugin would need a code stream account. [image]